# squid proxy for http to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, http-proxy, squid

I am trying to set up `Squid` proxy to get files from S3 over http.

I have following configuration

```
    visible_hostname squid

    acl localnet src 10.56.0.0/16
    acl localnet src 10.2.0.0/16

    acl s3 dstdom_regex .*s3\.us-west-1\.amazonaws\.com

    http_access allow localnet s3

    http_port 3128
    http_access deny all
```

But not able to get the file from S3 with on the subnet EC2

```
$ wget http://files.dev.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/file.tar.gz
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

What configuration I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong S3 URL. When I replace config with following

```
acl s3 dstdom_regex .*s3\.amazonaws\.com
```

S3 URL

```
wget http://files.dev.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/file.tar.gz
```